# VS2103 error: "Unable to start program - Class already exists" when I F5 to run site

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

This has been happening off and on for a couple weeks now. Everything will be working just fine, but at some point VS won't let me launch my site and I get the error

> Unable to start program '[my dev URL]'.
>   Class already exists.

I haven't changed any code-behind, just the HTML in my .ASPX page. If I restart VS I don't get the error and my site loads just fine.

I'm on Win7 SP1 using VS 2013 Ultimate Update 2. I have Web Essentials installed which I *think* was updated recently.

I've poked around online for a while and can't see anyone else reporting this error so I figured I'd post it here.

Comment: Is this an error you see in the browser?  Or something VS pops up?  Kinda sounds like some sort of plugin or extension.

Comment: It's something VS pops up. I can't quite remember if the browser even launches at that point. My hunch was plug-in also, which is why I reference Web Essentials.
On some occasions my whole desktop gets funky and windows stop opening/closing as I'd expect, also necessitating a reboot.
I did a repair of VS 2013 and so far so good.

Comment: You can also run `devenv.exe /SafeMode` to start VS and disable all plugins.

Comment: I wish it was easily reproducible so I could determine if its a plugin and which one. If I figure out how to make the error occur, I'll definitely use your /safemode idea. Thanks, Mike

Comment: @PTansey, error not appearing after repair ?